# Accessing file across network fails with "The system detected a possible attempt to compromise security."

Tags: vb.net, authentication, permissions, network-programming

Hi I am writing a WPF app that needs to access my files on another PC on my network (domain). My first try to access a remote folder has not been a raging success.

On my Windows 7 laptop I entered in Windows Explorer

> \\WIN-DCname\c$

, this is the path to C drive on my test domain controller, and when challenged I logged in with the administrator account for the DC. I can then access the folder tree of C drive as expected.

As a test application I used the following to probe that same drive:

```
Try
    Dim DirInfo As New DirectoryInfo("\\WIN-DCname\c$")
    Dim Dirs = DirInfo.GetDirectories.OrderByDescending(Function(x) x.FullName)
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

but the GetDirectories line throws an exception:

> The system detected a possible attempt to compromise security. Please
>   ensure that you can contact the server that authenticated you.

I'm starting to think there is a permissions problem here.... Do I have to programmatically authenticate again prior to doing this? If so how?

Or is it not possible to do a GetDirectories over the network? Is there another way?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it turns out that I needed to use [Impersonation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net), which lets me programmatically emulate another user while executing a block of code. No opening of ports was required.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft [explains it all as follows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938457):

**CAUSE** This problem occurs because the network firewall filters Kerberos traffic.

**RESOLUTION** To resolve this problem, configure the network firewall so that TCP port 88 and UDP port 88 are not blocked for either domain.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that article before I posted but its not relevant for my situation, it is specifically for "when you try to include security settings for a user from different domain in a local domain folder".

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple network connections - Wireless, Wired Ethernet**

The error “The system detected a possible attempt to compromise security.” started happening for me when I started alternately using a Wireless network connection at night and a wired Ethernet connection during the day.